# Error on copying to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

Hello i have a sub that copies from every sheet in the wb to a sheet named "Table", the sheets are structured with multiple tables and i need to copy the first table from the top, without the headers and aggregate every table contain from the sheets into sheet "Table":

```
Sub TableCopy()
Dim ws1  As Worksheet, _
LR1 As Long, _
LR2 As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws1.Name <> "Table" Then
    LR1 = Sheets("Table").Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    LR2 = ws1.Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 1
    ws1.Range("A:S" & LR2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Table").Range("A" & LR1)
End If
Next ws1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I'm getting

> Method Range of 'object' worksheet failed

I just can't get the grasp of it, can you help me? thx

Comment: Fully qualify this reference - `Rows.Count` - It's using `ActiveSheet` by default.

Comment: Which line throws an error?

Comment: The     
    ws1.Range("A:S" & LR2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Table").Range("A" & LR1) one

Comment: `"A:S" & LR2` will result in something like *A:S100*, this is incorrect address, try something along the line `"A9:S" & LR2`

Answer (score 0):

Two fixes:

```
Sub TableCopy()
Dim ws1  As Worksheet, _
LR1 As Long, _
LR2 As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each ws1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws1.Name <> "Table" Then
    LR1 = Sheets("Table").Range("H" & Sheets("Table").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Fix 1 (qualified the rows.count)
    LR2 = ws1.Range("B8", Range("B8").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count - 1
    ws1.Range("A2:S" & LR2).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Table").Range("A" & LR1) 'Fix 2 (added a # for starting row in copy range, assume row 1 is header)
End If
Next ws1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: If the paste range throws another error, you will most likely need to list a full destination range, rather than a single cell

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TableCopy()
Dim ws1  As Worksheet, _
LR1 As Long, _
LR2 As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each ws1 In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
If ws1.Name <> "Table" Then
    LR1 = Worksheets("Table").Cells(Worksheets("Table").Rows.count, "H").End(xlUp).row + 1
    LR2 = ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).row - 9
    ws1.Range("A2:S" & LR2).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Table").Range("A" & LR1)

End If
Next ws1
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```